# Backbone style: how to deal with the el element of a view

Tags: view, backbone.js

I find in several backbone examples different ways to do the same thing

I'd just like to know if any of them is better, and in case they're exactly the same which is the more accepted style

```
$('#header').html(new HeaderView().render());
```

vs

```
new HeaderView({el:$('#header')).render();
```

and

```
this.$el.html( this.template() );
```

vs

```
$(this.el).html( this.template() );
```

and finnally

```
render: function() {
    [...]
    return this.el;
}
```

vs

```
render: function() {
    [...]
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Prefer `this.$el` over `$(this.el)` since `$el` is already there. `return this;` in `render` is the *standard* that everyone probably expects. Sometimes you pass `el` to the constructor, sometimes you don't, it depends on circumstance. This is all opinion though so I'm voting to close (but there's your answer anyway).

Comment: @[opensas] - listen to mu.  @muistooshort - sure this question is phrased as 'what do you think', so I understand your close vote.  I remember, however, feeling like a deer-in-headlights with the immense flexibility of backbone, before I understood each component/elements role.  So I see the value in this question.

Comment: I do realize that it might look like a subjective question, but if you take a look at fguillen's and mu's answer you'll find very objective and concrete reasoning, regarding performance, decoupling and conventions... that's not merely opinionated stuff, IMHO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Send, or not to send, `el` in the constructor

I think always that is possible is better to send `el` in the constructor, this way the JS logic will be more *decoupled* from the DOM structure and not any DOM element name is hard-coded into the JS code.

This is also better for *testing* proposes so you don't need to recreate the production DOM structure in your tests and you can create a dummy DOM structure and instantiate your Views making reference to any DOM element in your dummy DOM structure.

Also the View becomes more reusable.

#### Using `this.$el`

I think in a performance point of view is better to use:

```
this.$el
```

VS

```
$(this.el)
```

Due the first option is already *precompiled*. jQuery consume resources transforming a simple DOM element in a jQuery DOM element and if you use `this.$el` this is done only once.

#### What to return in `render()`

As @muistooshort has said, the standard is to return `this`. Normally when you call `render()` what you only need from outside is `el` so returning `el` has a lot of logic but people has agreed to returning `this`.

In some way it has its logic due this expression looks awkward:

```
$('#header').html(new HeaderView().render())
```

But this other looks very much intuitive and self explained:

```
$('#header').html(new HeaderView().render().el)
```

Comment: great answer, intimately I was leaning towards the options you gave, but it was kind of intuitive...